# Removing duplicate concatenated values in a sql column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am updating a product bin location in our database using the reference text from a stock count we recently did. Some of the products have multiple bin locations, so I am using this SQL to pull all the bin locations into a table:

```
SELECT 
    SCT.ProductID,
    STUFF ((SELECT ',' + ReferenceText 
            FROM StockCounttickets SCT2
            WHERE SCT2.ProductId = SCT.ProductID 
              AND SCT2.StockCountID = '10873'
            ORDER BY ProductID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS Products
FROM 
    StockCountTickets SCT
WHERE 
    SCT.StockCountID = '10873'
GROUP BY 
    ProductID ;
```

I am getting the result I want, except for some of the products were counted twice in the same place, so some of the results have the same value twice

[image]

Is there any way to get rid of the duplicates?

Comment: Add `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` and before `','` in the `STUFF`.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you mean the duplicates in the concatenated list.

Well, you can just remove the duplicates using `select distinct` or `group by`:

```
SELECT SCT.ProductID,
       STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + SCT2.ReferenceText 
               FROM StockCounttickets SCT2
               WHERE SCT2.ProductId = SCT.ProductID AND 
                     SCT2.StockCountID = 10873
               ORDER BY SCT2.ProductID
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'
                                            ), 1, 1, '') AS Products
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SCT.ProductId
      FROM StockCountTickets SCT
      WHERE SCT.StockCountID = 10873
     ) SCT;
```

Notes:

- In a correlated subquery, you should qualify all column references, always, to avoid errors.
- Assuming `StockCountID` is a number, don't use quotes for the comparison.
- I prefer to generate the distinct rows in the subquery.  I believe this is a performance gain.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  Worked awesome.  Thank you for the advice, I need all I can get!

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this.  How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: @RobFritch . . . There should be an "accept" button near the top of the question.